# Are there any an university faculty for artificial (constructed) languages?

Tags: constructed-language

Are there currently any faculty on university that is dedicted for artificial languages, or has speciality for such languages? I mean, where you can study them, write Master's thesis for them, doctorise in such thematic.

Comment: Hello Stepan. This question is not constructive, because you're asking for a list.

Comment: [Conlangs are now on topic](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/433/111), but this question stays not constructive. If you could fix that, I'll reopen it (like I'm reopening others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not aware of any such place or academics that specialise in constructed languages, it is possible to research them for higher degree studies in linguistics. This is probably most true of departments which have a focus on descriptive/documentary linguistics. I am aware of one person who is doing a doctorate on a constructed language that is used for religious purposes by a group in an Asian country. Being a constructed language (and not anyone's first language) it is not complete, in the sense that there are numerous gaps in what can be expressed (ie things that all natural languages can express). For this reason a lot of the analysis is on the sociolinguistics of the situation that led to the construction of the language and which continues to support its continued usage.

It has been suggested that Classical Sanskrit can be considered a constructed language. Classical Sanskrit may be studied at many universities and it is quite possible to do higher degree research on it.

Comment: For what it's worth, Classical Sanskrit is not a constructed language. Rather it is a "crystallized/frozen language":‌ centuries of grammatical tradition, of attempting to describe real _spoken_ language, culminated in the work of Pāṇini etc. which gave a complete frozen description of the language, which all later works/usage have adhered to. So it is similar to constructed languages in the sense that there is a canonical fixed authority for what is grammatical in the language, but it's not constructed in the sense of having been created out of whole cloth.